# communication of devices using serial port in java

Tags: java, serial-port

- How to do this kind of communication?
- What libraries are available?
- How is    the data seen as bits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serial on Java is a bit tricky to get started, but once you've got it up and running, it's quite straightforward.

Serial is not implemented in a uniform way on different OS's, so Sun's approach was to develop the JavaComm *specification* and a *reference implementation*. For better or worse, Sun appeared to lose interest several years ago, and dropped Windows support in 2005.

So, the reference implemetation has largely been 'superceded' by a project called RXTX. RXTX works with Windows, Linux, BSD, Mac etc, so this is normally reason enough to use it.

Both these implementations require use of a native library (.so or .dll), which needs to be installed & configured in a per-platform way.

See this link for a balanced introduction, including code samples:
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Serial_Programming/Serial_Java

Here is the RXTX project: http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

HTH

Edit: in answer to your final question, the javacomm SerialPort class provides  getInputStream() and getOutputStream() methods, so you can use these as you normally would in java.io

Answer (score 0):

Java Communications API.

Starting here might get to you info you need:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-141752.html